# Outlook signature personalized to show days that i'm not working

Tags: outlook

So this month and next month i'm working parttime. Every week i'm available on another day. I would like to have a signature that shows on what day i'm not available.
I could change it myself every week but i'm looking for a solution where it could be done automaticaly. Does anyone have an idea how i could do this? or where i could find more information or where i could start?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signatures are stored as files in a directory

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures
```

For `HTML` formatted mails, the signature has an `.htm` extension.

To achieve a dynamic signature, you could write a program (or `VBA` macro) which rewrites your mail signature file. In `HTML` or `Text` format, this is not that hard.